# How do I get the buttons in an Ext.FormPanel?

Tags: extjs

I cannot see to get the buttons from an Ext.FormPanel defined like this:

```
Ext.apply({
    ....
    buttons: [
        {
            text: 'Save',
            itemId: 'btnSave'
        }
    ]
});
```

I've tried getComponent on the FormPanel instance, but that doesn't return btnSave. Is btnSave on a different element than the rest of the form?

Comment: You could also try `panel.down('#btnSave')`

Comment: Can you show the rest of the config? Also, what version of ExtJS are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `getComponent()` because the buttons are not part of the `items` config.

getComponent() - "Examines this container's items property and gets a direct child component of this container."

You could give the button an `id` and then use `Ext.getCmp()` or use component query as @limscoder shows.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use the container's "query" method to retrieve descendant components:

panel.query("#btnSave")

Comment: As of ExtJS 4.1.0, you can also use AbstractContainer's queryById('btnSave') to get the single component instead of query()'s array.

See http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.container.AbstractContainer

Answer (score 0):

In Extjs 4.2, I had similar code to yours with buttons at the bottom of a window.
This worked for me:

```
var bbar = this.getDockedItems('toolbar[dock="bottom"]')[0];
var button = bbar.getComponent('btnSave');
```

The toolbar and items are not in your code but they are implied with buttons:[{}]